# Office Interop File Not Found

Tags: c#, ms-access, interop

I have seen this issue in other places. But, I feel mine is different enough that it deserves its own question.

I have been building a project that uses the COM interop libraries for MS Access and MS Access DAO. They worked fine and then suddenly they didn't. Literally while running unit tests, one test was good, then, the next was not and now it won't run.

The error is the typical one:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Of course, the assembly is NOT "office", rather, it is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access/Dao.

The offending code is below:

```
_database = new AccessDb(Resources.AccessDatabaseFilePath, connectionStringBuilder, false, false);
```

The ctor looks like this:

```
public AccessDb(string pathToAccessFile, OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder, bool visible, bool readonlyMode)
{
    _connectionStringBuilder = connectionStringBuilder;
    _accessDbFileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToAccessFile);

    if (!File.Exists(pathToAccessFile))
        return;

    if (IsFileTooLarge())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Access Db file has become too large. Please address file size before continuing.");
    }

    if (readonlyMode) return;

    _access = new MicrosoftAccess.Application();

    try
    {
        _access.OpenCurrentDatabase(pathToAccessFile);
        _db = _access.CurrentDb();
        _access.Visible = visible;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _access.Visible = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        //insert code to possibly recover backup copy of access file.
    }
}
```

Feel free to critique my code. If you find any mistakes or bad practices, I'd be happy to have the feedback. But my primary concern is getting the interop libraries to work again.

I manually copied them into the debug directory and then referenced them from there. Which worked up until yesterday.

Finally, here is what my csproj file looks like.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="cprd.json" />
  <None Remove="CPRD_DB.accdb" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <COMReference Include="MDACVer">
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    <VersionMinor>50</VersionMinor>
    <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
    <Guid>54af9343-1923-11d3-9ca4-00c04f72c514</Guid>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
  </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="cprd.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.143" />
  <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="6.2.7" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetStandard" Version="1.0.118" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OleDb" Version="7.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>


<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access">
    <HintPath>bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao">
    <HintPath>bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```